# How to modify a column of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

One column of my dataframe its in the following format:

```
{'name': 'Aimo'}
{'name': 'Aimo'}
{'name': 'Aimo'}
{'name': 'Aimo'}
{'name': 'Aimo'}
```

The `dtype` of the column is `object`. How can I modify this column in the following format?

```
Aimo
Aimo
Aimo
Aimo
Aimo
```

Probably the new `dtype` would be `character`. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I guess if they're dictionaries, do:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str['name']
```

Or parse them as dictionaries if they are not already:

```
from ast import literal_eval
df['column'] = df['column'].map(literal_eval).str['name']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html):

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str.get('name')
```